# Session variables from form not showing on next page

Tags: php, session

I can set session variables and use them on another page. However when i try to use a simple contactform with a username and email address and try to store them into session variables, they don't show up on other pages. There must be something basic i'm missing.

Here's the form:

```
<?php
session_start();
$submit = $_POST["submit"];
if($submit){setSessionVars();}
function setSessionVars() {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    header('Location: session.php');
}
?>

<html>
<body>
  <form action="session.php" method"post">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="Name" size="11" /><br />
    <input name="email" type="text" value="Email" size="11" /><br /><br />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" size="11" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is session.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Also

```
header('Location: session.php');
```

is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: When you submit the form to session.php, do you get any values? It doesn't look like you are calling setSessionVars() on that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a glance, I see one immediate problem that will keep the form from posting.

```
<form action="session.php" method"post">
```

You need an "=" sign between method and "post".

Changing that alone will give you the "t" in session.php.

Answer (score 1):

You post the form to `session.php`:

```
<form action="session.php" method"post">
```

I'd change it to:

```
<form method="post">
```

That way, the page posts to itself. Then it can register the session variables and redirect the user to `session.php`.

Edit: also, you forgot the `=` sign in `method"post"`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but
    header('Location: session.php');
doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Edited my answer, you wrote `method"post"` instead of `method="post"`. :)